# How to fetch huge JSON data from HTTP in Android?

Tags: android, httpresponse

This is my code and my string `line` does not read the entire response:

```
    int bufferSize = 10240 ; // 10KB.
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStream),bufferSize);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            inStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What do you expect and where is your problem? Please be more specific.

Comment: while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null). the String line doesnot read the entire content. It stops half way through. My response from HTTP is big and it only reads half of my response

Comment: Am also trying to find a code where i can write the httpresponse directly to a file.From the file i would like to store it in SQLite.

Comment: As the methodname says readLine() only reads the content until the next newline-character is found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get the whole response as `String` with `sb.toString()`.

If you want to store the result directly to a file you can use something like this:

```
private void storeToFile(InputStream input, String destFilename) {
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
        fos = new FileOutputStream(destFilename, false);

        int read = 0;
        while (read >= 0) {
            if (read > 0) {
                fos.write(buffer, 0, read);
                fos.flush();
            }
            read = input.read(buffer, 0, buffer.size());
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e(getClass().getName(), "error saving stream", ex);
    } finally {
        if (fos != null) {
            try {
                fos.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
            fos = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Of course you can also store the response as `blob` or `String`in SQLite, but I'd rather store the response as private file using `openFileOutput(destFilename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)` instead of `new FileOutputStream(destFilename, false)`. You can then store the filename in your SQLite-database. This keeps the SQLite-DB-file smaller and your queries will be faster. But you are not able to use your responsetext as filter in your queries.

Comment: You can accept the answer, if it solved your problem and answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

You should try GZIPInputStream to fix such kind of issue.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/GZIPInputStream.html